# Trying to make Vue Modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Im making my first vue modal and I want to make a simple pop up window when you click on a button. I followed a tutorial but it wouldnt work. Then I tried others and... same result. I have no idea what I'm doin wrong!

My modal component code in the template:

```
<div class="save-btn">
  <button @click="showModal = true">Save</button>
</div>
<transition name="modal-fade">
  <div class="modal-overlay" @click="$emit('close-modal')">
    <div class="modal" @click.stop>
      <h6>Saved!</h6>
      <p>Your Details have been saved Successfully</p>
      <button>Go Home</button>
    </div>
    <div class="close" @click="$emit('close-modal')">
      <img class="close-img" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</transition>
```

My modal compant code in the script:

```
data () {
    return {
        showModal: false
  }
}
```

When I click the button :

```
<div class="save-btn"><button u/click="showModal = true">Save</button></div>
```

absolutely nothing happens and I have no idea why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `v-if` for your [Transition](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#the-transition-component)

```
<div v-if="showModal" class="modal-overlay" @click="$emit('close-modal')">
```

Also you should stick to the regular syntax so use *Transition* instead of *transition* since it is a component.

[Here is the working demo of your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-playground-forked-8ddqkn?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: `Transition` is a baked-in component of Vue, it may need to be changed if an HTML one comes at some point but until then, OP can totally write it as `kebab` case like that, in the same way as `transition-group`. I do agree that it can be tricky especially when people name their components `Menu` or `Header` for sure.